# Video memory required for desktop virtualization

Tags: virtualization, desktop, video, graphics-processing-unit

I am planning to set up 3 virtual desktops using vmware. I have this [server](http://www.supermicro.com/products/system/1U/6015/SYS-6015W-U.cfm) with video memory of 32mb and 32 GB RAM.

What is the recommended video memory for this set up and is it possible to upgrade video memory on the server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any explanation instead of down votes would surely help

Comment: You post shows a lack of understanding of virtual hardware, you don't mention a specific hypervisor, the question lacks detail and you don't have a server with 32GB of video memory I'm sorry. Basically this feels like the question of a beginner and this site isn't for beginners. That was my reason anyway, can't speak for others.

Comment: 32gb was a typo. planning to use esxi to install virtual desktop. Didn't know this site is not for beginners..Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For virtual machine, the physical video memory of your server is not used, so it's not a problem.
And besides, on servers, you don't do graphic intensive stuff, you only display a linux console or a windows desktop with low graphic needs, unless you're planning to use your server to do 3D stuff, but in this case, the graphic cards is so important that you wouldn't ask ;)

Your setup will work easily.

Comment: No idea why someone downvoted your answer Thomas, it's correct for all cases unless you need 3D accelerated virtual GPUs.

Comment: My bad. I had multiple windows open and downvoted the wrong answer. Thomas, if you'll make an edit to this answer I'll upvote it to correct my mistake. Apologies.

Comment: The edit is needed in order for me to upvote this answer, otherwise I'm locked out from upvoting it.

Answer (score 2):

The amount of video memory is dictated by maximum screen resolution you expect to use. I think ESXi provides some sort of calculator with their client but rougly it is screen_width x screen_height x 4. I usually set 16mb as it is good enough for up to 4K resolution, so your 32MB is a plenty.

**Update:** Based on your comment I think you are missing an important point. You don't need video memory for the server itself. All you may want from the server is to show the BIOS screen and then ESXi console. Any basic video card will do that. *Video memory for virtual machines is allocated from your main memory*.

Comment: Thanks, I am shopping for some used equipment to set up home lab and learn virtualization. This really helped me

Comment: @SridharChidurala: I think I misunderstood your question. I updated my reply.